# rospy absolute duration bug

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I use ROS hydro and I think I found an error in the code of the rospy.Duration class

When I do :

> print abs(rospy.Duration.from_sec(0.5))

it prints -500000000 instead of 500000000. That's because the code only takes into account the number of seconds.
cf : https://github.com/ros/genpy/blob/indigo-devel/src/genpy/rostime.py

```
def __abs__(self):
    """
    Absolute value of this duration
    :returns: positive :class:`Duration`
    """
    if self.secs > 0:
        return self
    return self.__neg__()
```

It should be :

```
def __abs__(self):
    """
    Absolute value of this duration
    :returns: positive :class:`Duration`
    """
    if self.secs < 0 or (self.secs == 0 and self.nsecs<0):
        return self.__neg__()
    return self
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212267/rospy-absolute-duration-bug/) by [jbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22707/jbv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-26**:
I think you'd better report this to the `genpy` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros/genpy/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK. I did it here: https://github.com/ros/genpy/issues/35

---

Originally posted by [jbv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22707/jbv/) with karma: 11 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1